# how to sort [json] use SwiftyJSON in swift 4.x?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

```
import SwiftyJSON

let myData: [JSON] = [{"number": "1"}, {"number": "4"}, {"number": "3"}]

let sortedData = myData.sorted { $0["number"].stringValue > $1["number"].stringValue }
print(sortedData) // nil
```

How can I sort without changing to a dictionary?

I want to sort by value in order of high or low.

Is the value in the array not JSON?

I simply thought that the array values do not matter what they come in because the array acts as a sort.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use square brackets when declaring the JSON string for SwiftyJSON.

**sorted** will return a sorted elements and will not modify the original contents.

```
let myData: [JSON] = [["number": "1"], ["number": "4"], ["number": "3"]]
let sortedData = myData.sorted { $0["number"].stringValue > $1["number"].stringValue }
    print(sortedData)
```

Comment: mydata is not what I defined.
This is just an example.
It is the data received from the server.
It is not a square bracket when you print it.

Comment: I just used your example where you used a curly bracket. Using a square brackets sorted the data.  Do you have a sample of what you are getting from the server? and how are you calling it?

Comment: sorry. The data was approaching incorrectly. The way I know it is right.